# How can we use public key to connect to a SFTP server using JSch from an application hosted in server

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

We have to connect to an external SFTP server from our application using proxy server internet.ford.com by configuring username, password, and public key.

We are facing java code with JSch library to connect to the SFTP server. We are facing an issue when we are trying to connect the SFTP server from our application hosted in a server environment(Dev, QA)

I am getting `UnknownHostKey` exception as shown in the below log.

```
4463 [8/19/19 12:05:06:301 EDT] 0001fadf TransCommunic I   JSchException @  TransCommunicationMgr:- connect Result Code: UnknownHostKey: 74.126.93.138. RSA key fingerprint is e8:90:a9:f3:3d:8f:83:26:e3:24:2b:2f:a1:71:e3:7c
```

I set the public key as a byte array value in the below code chunk.

```
// knownHostPublicKey is a String variable 
knownHostPublicKey=config.getKnownHostPublicKey();

jsch.setKnownHosts(new 
ByteArrayInputStream(knownHostPublicKey.getBytes()));
```

Added the complete code that involves SFTP connection process to the show some code section.

I tried SFTP server connection using java JSch library and through proxy server internet.ford.com

```
public Session connectSFTP(final FtpCredentials config)
throws OfBusinessRuntimeException{
final String METHOD_NAME = "connect";
log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, config);

    /*Local attributes declaration */
    String host = null;
    String user = null;
    String password = null;
    int elapsedTime = 0;
    int sftpPort = 0;
    String knownHostPublicKey = null;
    String sftpProxy = null;
    int sftpProxyPort=0;
    Session sftpSession = null;
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    /* Beginning of try catch block */
    try {

        // Getting FTP connection details.
        if (config != null) {
            host = config.getHost();
            user = config.getUserId();
            sftpPort = config.getSftpPort();
            password = config.getPassword();
            elapsedTime = config.getElapsedTime();
            knownHostPublicKey=config.getKnownHostPublicKey();
            /*byte[] hostPublicKey=Base64.getDecoder().decode(knownHostPublicKey);
            HostKey hostKey=new HostKey(host,hostPublicKey);
            jsch.getHostKeyRepository().add(hostKey,null);
            */                

            jsch.

            jsch.setKnownHosts(new ByteArrayInputStream(knownHostPublicKey.getBytes()));

            sftpProxy=config.getSftpProxy();
            sftpProxyPort=config.getSftpProxyPort();
            sftpSession = jsch.getSession(user, host, sftpPort);
        }
        log.info("Before Connect " + host + " User :- " + user);
        if (host == null || user == null || password == null) {
            throw new OfBusinessRuntimeException(
                    "SFTP Host Information not found.");
        }
        sftpSession.setHost(host);
        sftpSession.setPassword(password);
        sftpSession.setPort(sftpPort);

        //java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        // // force aes256-ctr encryption
        //config.put("cipher.s2c", "aes256-ctr");
        //config.put("cipher.c2s", "aes256-ctr");
        //config.put("CheckCiphers", "aes256-ctr");
        //session.setConfig(config);

        sftpSession.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(sftpProxy,sftpProxyPort));
        /*
         * Setting the timeout to 30 seconds to ensure connection is made
         * for testing setting the port to 22 as this should be the one
         * to accept the connection
         **/

        sftpSession.setTimeout(elapsedTime);
        sftpSession.connect();
        log.info("SFTP Session Connection is successful");

    } catch (final JSchException jschException) {
        jschException.printStackTrace();
        log.info("JSchException @  TransCommunicationMgr:- "
                 + METHOD_NAME + " Result Code: "
                 + jschException.getMessage());
        //throw new OfBusinessRuntimeException(jschException.getMessage(),jschException);
    }
    /* Log existing method. */
    log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, sftpSession);
    return sftpSession;
}
```

Expects the connection to an external SFTP server is successful.

Comment: What is the value of `config.getKnownHostPublicKey()`?

Comment: It is bulk of alphanumetic characters like mhyrtt+ZdZpjUC+CeoQGEA got from the carrier system as their public key.

Comment: I have no idea what that is. It's not any public key or public key fingerprint format, I've ever seen. Definitely not something that JSch would accept.

Answer (score 1):

[`JSch.setKnownHosts`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setKnownHosts-java.io.InputStream-) accepts the public key in the format of OpenSSH `authorized_keys` file, which is like:

```
example.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA0hVqZOvZ7yWgie9OHdTORJVI5fJJoH1yEGamAd5G3werH0z7e9ybtq1mGUeRkJtea7bzru0ISR0EZ9HIONoGYrDmI7S+BiwpDBUKjva4mAsvzzvsy6Ogy/apkxm6Kbcml8u4wjxaOw3NKzKqeBvR3pc+nQVA+SJUZq8D2XBRd4EDUFXeLzwqwen9G7gSLGB1hJkSuRtGRfOHbLUuCKNR8RV82i3JvlSnAwb3MwN0m3WGdlJA8J+5YAg4e6JgSKrsCObZK7W1R6iuyuH1zA+dtAHyDyYVHB4FnYZPL0hgz2PSb9c+iDEiFcT/lT4/dQ+kRW6DYn66lS8peS8zCJ9CSQ==
```

That's not the format you use.

Comment: I saw in an online forum that we can set public key string value as follows jsch.setKnownHosts(new ByteArrayInputStream(knownHostPublicKey.getBytes())); 
                                                                                                                                
Also i don't know the project path of the file authorized_keys to be set if i use public key as file.

Comment: Yes, my answer does not oppose that. I say that the stream has to contain the data in the same format as `authorized_keys`.

Comment: The key file that the carrier team provide starts with "PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: rsa-key-20190705
Public-Lines: 6
gcIDetMQTFjwnXDMM5KLdzK..........remaining key value. Private-Lines: 14Should i set

Comment: That's user's private key. That has nothing to do with server host (public) key. Read my article on [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

Comment: Should i set entire content of the file as key value including "PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa" alongwith alphanumeric key value?

Comment: My application project structure is ProjectNameEAR->resources->properties->dev for Dev and qa for QA environment. Is it the right file path for the authorized_keys file that i can put it.

Comment: yes. you differentiate public and private key and provided a link to Understanding SSH key_pairs.

Comment: Not only public and private key, but **user's** private key  and **server/host** public key. So please read the article again to understand that these have nothing in common.

Comment: ok. here a quick question. for my requirement to connect to an external SFTP server what else is required to setup apart from userid and password (let me know whether i should use public key for knownhosts or not).

Comment: Can you authenticate to the server using the username and password when you use any standalone SSH client?